# Removing defaultdict from print statement

Tags: python, function, defaultdict

So I have a custom function that returns a default dict. This is how the value is currently returned as:

```
defaultdict(<function multi_level_dict at 0x0000014E2E099A60>, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

How can I turn this value into:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Preferably without using a for/while loop.

Comment: use `dict(your_default_dict)`. Note that it is really not necessary in order to work with the defaultdict.

Comment: You could make a subclass of `defaultdict` that replaces the stringification logic with that of `dict`. This will work even for the recursive case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a regular `dict` from a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>> dict(d)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Note that if the dict is nested such that some of the values are themselves defaultdicts, converting the top level dict won't do anything to those nested values.